# My google spreadsheet script only runs one function. Am I coding the script wrong?

Tags: java, javascript

The first function works fine and sorts but I cant get the second function that archives the row to work at the same time.

```
   function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var columnToSortBy = 10;
    var tableRange = "J:J3"; // What to sort. 

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );

        function onEdit2(event) {
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
            var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
            var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

            if(s.getName() == "Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == "5. Archive") {
                var row = r.getRow();
                var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
                var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
                var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
                s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
                s.deleteRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `onEdit2(event)` inside the if statement block, but you never execute it.

Defining a function inside of a block like that is bad practice. You can't really *conditionally* define a function. [See this link for more information on why this is bad.](http://jslinterrors.com/function-statements-should-not-be-placed-in-blocks)

It seems like you want to **execute** the `onEdit2` function if the `if` condition is true.

If so, you should define the function globally so you can execute it from wherever you need to.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
  function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var columnToSortBy = 10;
    var tableRange = "J:J3"; // What to sort. 

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );

        onEdit2(event);    // Execute the function, passing it whatever event was passed to onEdit
    }
  } // End definition of onEdit


function onEdit2(passedEvent) {     // Do the actual function definition out here
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = passedEvent.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == "5. Archive") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are amazing. I love you. (youve just got me a beer at work)

Comment: if i was to add a third function.

would it just be

onEdit3(passed event);
   }
}
Function onEdit3(PassedEvent) {
etc

Comment: You can define as many functions as you like. And if defined globally, you can call them from anywhere. So yes, you could add `function onEdit3(passedEvent) { //some code }` and then just call `onEdit3(event);` in `onEdit` if you wish.

Comment: You could actually call `onEdit3` from within `onEdit2` if you wanted to do it that way too.

Comment: i maybe doing something stupid but im calling the 3rd function in the same way as the second function and i cant get the 3rd function to work. does the method work for a number of functions?